# How to associate certain compiler flags with only certain targets

Tags: makefile

I want to define some macros only for some make targets. eg.

```
all : process1 process2

prcoess1: process1.c process.h

prcoess2: process2.c process.h

%.o:%.c
        $(CC) $(CCOPTS) -o $@ $<


CCOPTS += -DEXTRA1 
extra1 : clean all


CCOPTS += -DEXTRA2
extra2 : clean all
```

I want macro EXTRA1 to be defined only when I call `make extra1`. If I call `make` I don't want EXTRA1 to be defined. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extra1 : CCOPTS += -DEXTRA1 
extra1 : clean all

extra2 : CCOPTS += -DEXTRA2
extra2 : clean all
```

See [§6.11 Target-specific Variable Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) from the GNU make manual.